# how to learn size of absolute panel in gwt

Tags: gwt, size, height, width, panel

I can set width or height of an AbsolutePanel via setWidth() setHeight() methods, but there are no getWidht() or getHeight() methods. How can I get width or height after setting it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`getOffsetHeight()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/UIObject.html#getOffsetHeight%28%29) and [`getOffsetWidth()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/UIObject.html#getOffsetWidth%28%29). Be aware that these values include any padding or border present on the element.

You can also use [`Element#getClientWidth()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Element.html#getClientWidth%28%29) or [`Element#getClientHeight()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Element.html#getClientHeight%28%29), which won't include borders.

Comment: and also it is good to know that trying to get width and height before adding your widget to DOM will return 0.